# Why does scala convert Seq to List?

Tags: scala

```
> val a:Seq[Integer] = Seq(3,4)
a: Seq[Integer] = List(3, 4)
```

If `Seq` is only a trait, why does the compiler / REPL accept it, and does it behave like that for many other traits or even abstract classes?

Comment: The so far provided answer doesn't answer the part of the rationale for it, and whether this is sprinkled around much of the scala collections library. If there is a good one I'd be very happy to learn from it!

Comment: added some rationale ;)

Comment: Good one. 
[comment minimum length filler]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It doesn't convert anything.

`Seq` is a trait, you can't really instantiate it, only mix it in to some class.

Since `apply` method of the `Seq` companion object has to return some concrete class instance (that mixes in `Seq` trait), it returns a `List` which seems to be a reasonable default.

One situation this can be useful in, is when you need some `Seq` instance, but don't care about implementation and don't have time to look at the type hierarchy to find a suitable class implementing `Seq`. `Seq(3,4)` is guaranteed to give you something that obeys the `Seq` contract.

Comment: I'd like to learn more about it. Where is it defined that there is a default implementation? I don't see in the [Scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Seq) that the companion object says it has a default

Comment: @matt what other implementation of `Seq` would you use?

Comment: Of course it's reasonable, it just seems counterproductive to let you instantiate a trait, or instantiate collections in such an implicit way. Why is this useful? (and why is it not on the Scaladoc?)

Comment: Not so much counterproductive, just slightly counterintuitive. You can obviously opt out of using `Seq.apply` and avoid the problem completely.

Comment: @soulcheck `Vector` might also be a reasonable default

Comment: @acjay yes, that would be another good choice, though List is probably more light weight (being linked list by default) and prevalent in functional programming. `Vector` is the default implementation of `IndexedSeq`.

Comment: @matt It is in the scaladoc. It's a call to [`Seq.apply`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.Seq$).

Answer (score 7):

The default implementation for `Seq` is a List as mentioned in scaladoc here:

[Seq Object](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Seq$)

Which says

> This object provides a set of operations to create Seq values. The current default implementation of a Seq is a List.

When calling `Seq(3,4)` you actually invoke `Seq.apply(3,4)` which builds a sequence of two elements as a `List` underneath.